# VHS: no image rendered with <v:media.image additionalAttributes

Tags: typo3

I am using T3 8.6 and VHS 4.1.0. I want to render the pictures from tx_news using srcset, sizes etc. It all works well as long as i Use additionalAttributes to get the sizes. No Image is rendered anymore.

Here is my partial:

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
<v:media.image 
src="{newsItem.falMediaPreviews.0}" 
alt="{mediaElement.originalResource.alternative}" 
class="float-sm-none float-md-left news_header" 
srcset="300,600,900,1200"
treatIdAsReference="1"
additionalAttributes="{sizes:'(min-width: 90em) 900px,(min-width: 64em) 600px,(min-width: 30em) 100px,100vw'}"
```

Any Ideas what's wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

It's Working Fine. Just Closed the tag. with using Latest version of `flux` , `fluidcontent` and `vhs`

```
<v:media.image 
    src="{newsItem.falMediaPreviews.0}" 
    alt="{mediaElement.originalResource.alternative}" 
    class="float-sm-none float-md-left news_header" 
    srcset="300,600,900,1200"
    treatIdAsReference="1"
    additionalAttributes="{sizes:'(min-width: 90em) 900px,(min-width: 64em) 600px,(min-width: 30em) 100px,100vw'}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. The missing closing tag was a typo, it is included in my partial. I do not see what I am doing wrong. Using latest flux version 8.1.0. Concerning flux, do i need to include another viewhelper? (Sorry, not so familar yet with fluid etc.)